# Microsoft Visual Studio: service "xxx.yyy" has neither an image nor a build context specified: invalid compose project

Tags: .net, docker, visual-studio, asp.net-core, docker-compose

1. I have added a docker-compose project in Visual Studio 2022.
2. docker-compose project node was added in the solution with default `docker-compose.yml`, `docker-compose.override.yml` and `.dockerignore` files
3. `Dockerfile` was generated for project with WebAPI (ASP.Net Core project)
4. The content of docker-compose was edited, added additional services, network, etc.
5. When I try to display docker-compose project I get the error (error message box)

**`service "xxx.yyy" has neither an image nor a build context specified: invalid compose project`**

Similar message is displayed during solution rebuild (Code: DT1001)

6. There are no issues when I run `docker-compose -f 'docker-compose.yml' up --build` in PowerShell in solution explorer folder.

I would like to manage compose in VS and setup to start multiple containers from Visual Studio configuration. Can you help me fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that `docker-compose.override.yml` was misaligned with the `docker-compose.yml`. After copying `docker-compose.yml` to `docker-compose.override.yml` and editing only changed parts the problem was gone.